# Non-ASP.Net equivalent of MachineKey.Protect/Unprotect

Tags: c#, .net-4.5

Is there a simple to use encrypt/decrypt method outside the `System.Web.Security` namespace that are as easy to use as `MachineKey.Protect/MachineKey.Unprotect()`?

Or does anyone know if you can set up this outside ASP.Net as my quick trial showed that it seemed to generate a new key or something in between app restarts meaning you couldn't decrypt anything between restarts of the app.

I can roll my own using the appropriate classes, I was just wondering if they'd finally provided a simpler API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MachineKey in asp.net is autogenerated every time it starts up. To get around this you can [set the MachineKey](https://web.archive.org/web/20140804110856/http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey) explicitly.

Of course, if the process is running on the same machine as your potential hacker, it's all a bit pointless.

Answer (score 3):

I was searching for this as well. And after spent a few hours digging around, I found [`System.Security.Cryptography.ProtectedData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). The usage is very similar, just that you need to provide the scope. And here's the best part: it's available from .NET 2.0.

Hope this helps someone someday.

Comment: This seems like a pretty good solution, however one word of caution to anyone using this - read up on DPAPI first.  There are some gotchas, the big one being that this method is highly dependent on the user context under which it runs.  It's also pretty tightly coupled with Windows, so there *might* be the possibility of breaking changes over time.